# Execute Server Side from Client Side

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to execute the Add button click event(server side) from client side.

This is my javascript function

```
  function validateinput() {
    var arrTextBox = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
     var retVal = 1;
    for (i = 0; i < arrTextBox.length; i++) {
        if (arrTextBox[i].type == "text"  && arrTextBox[i].value == "") {
            retVal = 0;

        }
    }


    if (retVal == 0) {
        alert("Validation Failed");
        return false;
    }
    else {
        alert("Validation Success");
        return true;
        __doPostBack(btnAddItem);

    }

}
```

I am calling the server side code only when alert("Validation Sucess") and returns true.

This is my server side code

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtbox1.Attributes.Add("onkeydown", "if(event.keyCode) {if  (event.keyCode > 57 && event.keyCode <= 90)  return false; } else {return true};");
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            //The code is too big to be posted
        }
    }

    protected void btnAddItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsValidPost())
        {
            if (btnAddItem.Text == "Add Item +")
            {
                if (textbox1.text== "")
                {
                    Addtogrid();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Am I doing it the right way? as I am not getting the expected results. Also I get an error at  Page.GetPostBackEventReference(btnAddItem); saying ClientScript is a recommended way . When I try to use ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(btnAddItem); it throws an error stating ClientScript is not recognised.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

The onclick event of an asp:button object will call the [client validation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yb52a4x0.aspx) if you set it up with a validtion control.  If you have not set up the onclick event to the button it is not going to know what method to call.   If you have set up the onclick then the javascript call is not needed.  If you set up a validation control to use the validation script and the client side validation .net will handle the postback call.  And looking at your script you may be better served using a [required field validator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hbw267h%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) than your custom script.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you help me in getting the desired results?

Comment: The required field validator control has the functionality you want built in. you just need to add a RequiredFieldValidator for each of your textboxes that you want to require. If this is dynamic on page load you can add one for each and enable/disable them in your page load/databind event. Asp.net buttons by default cause validation.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you need the GetPostBackEventReference code in the page load method?  _doPostBack() doesn't the target object to be referenced, just the name.

Edit: Why are you calling return true before calling _doPostBack()?

Edit 2: There are 2 ways to call GetPostBackEventReference, 1) from your .NET code [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0d5ytaxf.aspx) but this is an obsolete method and the client side script version is recommended, 2) from your client side script [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.getpostbackeventreference.aspx).  I can't tell which method you are using because you didn't post the page load code.  I don't see a reason to call it based on the other code you posted.  The call to _doPostBack() can operate without getting the post back reference for a control.

Remove the call to GetPostBackEventReference and change your javascript to look like this:

```
function validateinput() {
    var arrTextBox = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    var ddlTextBox = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
    var retVal = 1;
    for (i = 0; i < arrTextBox.length; i++) {
        if (arrTextBox[i].type == "text" && arrTextBox[i].getAttribute("IsMandatory") == "Y" && arrTextBox[i].value == "") {
            retVal = 0;
        }
    }

    if (retVal == 0) {
        alert("Validation Failed");
        return false;
    }
    else {
        alert("Validation Success");
        __doPostBack('btnAddItem', '');
        return true; // This shouldn't be needed but it does need to come after _doPostBack()
    }
}
```

Edit 3: Try the following code for the button:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnAddItem" runat="server" onclick="btnAddItem_Click" OnClientClick ="javascript:validateinput(); return false;" Text="Add Item +" Width="85px" />
```

The OnClientClick code needs to return false if you don't want it to post back to the form. Even if you return false from a called JavaScript method, it will still post back.  This has never made sense to me but I've learned it through repeatedly having this same issue.

Comment: @Chris, I quite did not understand the first line in your answer. Can you help me understand it with code if possible?

Comment: @Chris, I tried the code above and I have pasted my Page Load Method but if the validation fails it does nto display the alert box.

Comment: Can you post all your code? It is difficult to glean what you are doing with these code blocks.

Comment: @jackey, does it display the successful message or does it fail before it gets to the if block?  What calls validateInput()?

Comment: <asp:Button ID="btnAddItem" runat="server" onclick="btnAddItem_Click" OnClientClick ="javascript:validateinput();" Text="Add Item +" Width="85px" /> I am using this to call validateinput And even if the validation fails teh server side code executes . If the validation is sucessfull , it displays teh sucess message but the code does not get executed...

Comment: @jackey, Use the code posted above in Edit 3 to try and stop the post back when the validation fails.  If it works we'll then address the doPostBack() call from JavaScript.

Comment: @Chris, now it does not post back when the validation fails ...can you help with the post back when the validation succeeds

Comment: @Chris , i tried will this line  alert("Validation Success");
          //  var button = document.getElementById('<%=btnAddItem.ClientID %>');
           // __doPostBack(button.name, "OnClick");

            return true; It is giving me the below error "Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using <pages enableEventValidation="true"/> in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.